# Can SharePoint 2013 crawl Exchange 2010

Tags: search, exchange

Can a shared mailbox be crawled by SP 2013 on Exchange 2010?

Answer (score 2):

•         We have SharePoint Server 2013 installed and have setup the Search Service Application.
Currently we are crawling various content sources which all work fine. However we are having issues with showing correct results for Exchange Public Folders 2010. We have setup the content source and crawl rule as described here: 
Link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591608.aspx

The result is that it appears to be crawling and indexing the Exchange public folders, but when we do a search and click on any of the files in the results it goes to a “400 bad request – internet explorer” page, instead of the file. 
Comparing the URL in the result to the actual link to the item can be seen below:

- From SP2013 Search:

owa.domain.local/owa/?a=Open&id=PSI%2ELgAAAAAaRHOQqmYRzZvIAKoAL8RaAwA9cszZSZ%252boSbNVbF46CThNAAAFC0q2AAAB%2ERgAAAAAaRHOQqmYRzZvIAKoAL8RaCQA9cszZSZ%252boSbNVbF46CThNAAAFC0q2AACebOdFTZ%252b0R59CZOjC7d5oAAAKwY2DAAAA&t=&ae=Item

- Right Exchange URL and generated URL in Crawl Log:

owa.domain.local/owa/?a=Open&id=PSI.LgAAAAAaRHOQqmYRzZvIAKoAL8RaAwA9cszZSZ%2boSbNVbF46CThNAAAFC0q2AAAB%2ERgAAAAAaRHOQqmYRzZvIAKoAL8RaCQA9cszZSZ%2boSbNVbF46CThNAAAFC0q2AACebOdFTZ%2b0R59CZOjC7d5oAAAKwY2DAAAA&t=&ae=Item

So it looks like a problem with the encoding? URL is encoded (. in %2e and % in %25)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can index public folders, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591608.aspx
If you really need shared mailboxes, have a look at available connectors from Raytion or BA-Insight. Alternatively, you can federate search results from Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Item_CommonItem_Body.html 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ff4900a6-2d82-4b57-9aa4-a6e21f6eac37/search-in-exchange-public-folder?forum=sharepointsearch